# Encryption of Request and Decryption of Response

Tags: angular, spring-boot, encryption, request, response

I have a requirement to make the data in network layer not human understandable (request and response). Problem is that the API code has over 100 endpoints, and I don't want to make changes to entire codebase to do decryption of request and encryption of response on every method to accustom with this. I was wondering if there is a simple way implement this so that there is not much code changes. I am also searching for packages also to do this, didn't find any. The API is developed with Spring Boot and UI using Angular. Appreciate the help!!

I tried making changes in controller but that's an overhead since it has to be changed in all methods.

Comment: Have you explored middleware in spring boot? and interceptors in Axios? With these, you can manage encryption, and decryption at a single place in each project.

Comment: I have tried doing encryption and decryption in API filter. But the problem being I'm not able to modify the response and the request body once accessed, becomes null in the controller.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: *... make the data in network layer not human understandable ...* Use HTTPS, like everybody else.

Comment: Hi @PresidentJamesK.Polk, that's basic yes... There are instances that the developer tools have been misused. Let's say u have a door, with two locks in it, and I'm the type of person who wants to lock both. Thank you for the suggestion by the way.